# Need to increase the stability margin of the crystal

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, oscillator, crystal

I'm using the below crystal in the below [KSZ8863](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00002335B.pdf) IC.

[image]

[image]

Empirical try-and-fail shows that the current of the crystal can be easily reduced by changing the primary selected capacitors (2x22 pF) to e.g. 2x10 pF. By changing the capacitors there is improvement with gain margin too.

What is needed for a given quartz to decrease the power of the crystal (not increase by increasing capacitance value)?

Any ideas to improve the stability margin of the crystal?

Comment: Not sure what the question asks. Do you want to reduce power or incerease gain margin, as they are two somewhat contradicting operations, or both? What in the circuit you are allowed  to change to achieve something? Are you allowed to change the chip, or the crystal, or just the load caps and series resistor?

Comment: Stability margin cannot be the right term for an oscillator and neither can gain margin. What does "Empirical try-and-fail" mean?

Comment: @Justme, I want to reduce the power. I want to modify the crystal

Comment: Have you looked at the Reference Design to see what values they use?

Comment: @Finbarr, I looked at the reference design. They seem to use 2x 18pF capacitors. Not sure what crystal part they are using. I want to reduce the power of the crystal ideally. Since, the load capacitance of the crystal is 10pF, I don't want to increase the values of the load capacitance which would increase the power levels.

Comment: You should know there are crystals sold with a Frequency Tolerance at +25°C of +-10 ppm and Frequency Stability over the Operating Temp. (Ref to +25°C) of +- 10 ppm. But there are others with +- 50 ppm for both. If we use +- 100 ppm for both errors, for a day of 24 hours the error may be up to +- 8.64 seconds, or 259.2 seconds for a month of 30 days. For a year the error may be up 52 minutes and 34 seconds. Using a quartz with +- 20 ppm for both errors you get 10 minutes and 31 seconds.

Comment: @Uwe, thank you for the comment. Could you let me know how to decrease the power levels?

Comment: If I would try to decrease the power consumption of microprocessor, I would think about using a slower crystal or sleep mode. The capacitors you want to change are needed for  a stable clock. I do not recommend to change them to decrease power.

Comment: Just how much power do you think you can save?

Comment: And how are you measuring the power consumed by the crystal?

Comment: @Newbie How much is the crystal power consumption, and is it a problem, and why do you need to reduce power consumption of the crystal? Is the drive level over the 200 microwatt limit?

Comment: Try increasing the value of R5800 (now 47 ohms) to decrease crystal current. Its very low value now makes no sense. Should likely be kilo-ohms. Seems like an XY problem - what you expect to achieve by decreasing crystal current is suspect.

Comment: "improve the stability margin of the crystal" do you think of the frequency stability over temperature of the crystal f_tem -20 to + 20 ppm? If you want to improve the frequency stability over temperature, you should use a temperature compensated crystal oscillator (crystal and oscillator within the same package) instead of the crystal only. If you are not satisfied with a compensated version, you need an oven controlled crystal oscillator. It has a built in heater with controller to operate at a constant temperature.